# Kafka Server - Could not find a 'KafkaServer' in JAAS

Tags: apache-kafka, jaas, sasl

I have a standalone kafka broker that I'm trying to configure SASL for. Configurations are below.  I'm trying to set up SASL_PLAIN authentication on the broker.

My understanding is that with the listener.name... configuration in the server.properties, I shouldn't need the jaas file. But I've experimented with one to see if that might be a better approach.

I have experimented with each of these commands, but both result in the same exception.

- `sudo bin/kafka-server-start etc/kafka/server.properties`
- `sudo -Djava.security.auth.login.config=etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf bin/kafka-server-start etc/kafka/server.properties`

the exception displayed is:

> Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown... Could
>   not find a 'KafkaServer' or 'sasl_plaintext.KafkaServer' entry in the
>   JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config'
>   is not set

server.properties:

```
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
listener.security.protocol.map: SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT
listener.name.SASL_PLAINTEXT.plain.sasl.jaas.config:
            org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required /
username="username" /
password="Password" /
user_username="Password";  

advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://[ipaddress]:9092
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
secutiy.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

kafka_server_jaas.conf:

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="username"
   password="Password"
   user_username="Password";
};
```

I've spent a day looking at this already - has anyone else had experience with this problem?

Comment: `sudo -Djava...` doesn't do anything (you shouldn't even need sudo to run Kafka)... Are you sure you setup that correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting my mistakes here for austerity:

- Don't do your startup commands from the cli, put them in a .sh file and run from there:
  For example, something like this:

zkstart

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=etc/kafka/zookeeper_jaas.conf"
bin/zookeeper-server-start etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties &
```

kafkastart

```
export KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf
bin/kafka-server-start etc/kafka/server.properties
```

- If you still encounter an error related to the configs, check your _jaas files to ensure all the configuration sections in the error messages are present. If they are, it's likely the format isn't quite correct - check for the two semi-colons in each section and if that fails, try recreating the file entirely from scratch (or from a c&p from the documentation).

**edit**
So, the final solution for me was to add the export.... lines to the beginning of the corresponding kafka-server-start and zookeeper-server-start files.  It took me a while before the 'everything is a file' finally clicked and I realized the script files were the actual basis for the services.

Comment: BTW, if you install Confluent Platform, then it offers systemctl startup/stop scripts

Comment: I tried the same command but unable to run kafka server. Can you please look into the details? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60927205/exception-while-loading-zookeeper-jaas-login-context-and-could-not-find-a-kafka

Answer (score 5):

You need to export a variable, not in-line the config to kafka-server-start (or `sudo`).

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
bin/kafka-server-start /path/to/server.properties
```

Ref. [Confluent's sections on Kafka security](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html#kafka-sasl-auth)

Comment: I would recommend the full tutorial, too https://docs.confluent.io/current/tutorials/security_tutorial.html